# Proper way of connecting wires to pins on polymer films

Tags: contact, clamp

What is the **proper way to connect** wires to contacts from a thin semitransparent "plastic" foil (see images). There are slightly different types; *the first one with the 4 pins in a row is the more important one*)? It is a thinflexible foil with pressure sensors, which are connected via the thin metal streaks to the "pins" on the right.

Just solder, or are there kind of clamps that I can use? Are there any normed/standardized connectors/clamps? I'd like the contacts to be as "non-destructive" as possible (considering my current soldering skills, to be honest, but I can try to improve), and to be absolutely **as flat and stable as possible** (max. 1 mm (ok, maybe I have to relax that to about 3 mm), must stand a person's weight stepping on them multiple times).

I was searching on the web for a long time w/o success, and realize I may not even know the **correct term for this kind/type of electronic constructions on foils**, so even that might help a little bit - **may I ask you to tell me the correct name?**

[image]

[image: s]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that they are shaped more pointedly at the end suggests that these are in fact meant to be directly soldered.

> max. 1 mm,

soldering seems to be your only option, then.

> must stand a person's weight stepping on them multiple times

That sounds questionable, at best. Wire-to-anything-solid connections are notoriously prone to breaking under repeated stress; you'd want to add enough housing and strain relief to make sure pressure is **only** (if at all) applied flat on the contacts, and nothing pulls or shears on the cable connection.

In fact, since this probably has to go into a housing with confined space: Consider designing a flex PCB with matching contacts on one and, solder to that, and use it to get the signal out of the mechanically stressed region.